# Golang os.Rename(<fromDir>,<toDir>) not working in Windows

Tags: windows, go, operating-system, directory, rename

Using Go - lang, according to the documentation, the os.Rename should be able to rename either a file or directory on any operating system.

On Linux it works as it should, pass either a file or directory into it and the file or directory are moved.

On windows i recieve an 'Access is denied' Error when trying to pass a folder. 
 It works 100% for files.

example:
source = c:\sourcefolder
destination = c:\destinationfolder

source contains:
C:\sourcefolder\file1.xml
C:\sourcefolder\file2.xml
C:\sourcefolder\foldername1
C:\sourcefolder\foldername1\file3.xml
C:\sourcefolder\foldername2
C:\sourcefolder\foldername2\file4.xml

both file1.xml and file2.xml will successfully copy to c:\destination.
But the folders and files within the folders crash out with access denied

The script is pretty simple:

```
source := "C:\\sourcefolder"
destination := "C:\\destinationfolder"
pathSeperator := "\\"

files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(source)
    if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Move command execution error: ", err)
    }

for _, f := range files {
    fmt.Println(f.Name())
    fmt.Println(f.Mode())
    err := os.Rename(source+pathSeperator+f.Name(), destination+pathSeperator+f.Name())
    if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Move command execution error: ", err)
    panic(err)
    }
}
```

Having searched stackoverflow and golang's resources, i found the issue listed in 2016 that reported this fault and according to the issue it was fixed, but i am unable to get this to work. Nowhere else that i can find lists this issue go golang.

checking the f.Mode for access, i get drwxrwxrwx and have complete access to all the files and directories.

Any help with this would be great, racking my mind.  Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried moving (renaming) just the directory and not its files one-by-one? Do you create the destination folder prior to running the above code? Doc of `os.Rename()` also states: "_OS-specific restrictions may apply when oldpath and newpath are in different directories."_

Comment: I have, have tried creating the destination first, have tried empty folders, etc. The main purpose is to speed up an existing process which uses robocopy. By using this function on linux to move 500mb worth of folders compared to using mv, increased efficiency by 2300%! Why i am keen to use it in windows too, especially as the os function is designed to be generic. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried simply `os.Rename(source, destination)` with `destination` deleted prior?

Comment: Unfortunately yes :(

Comment: All I can suggest is raising a new Github issue and referencing the other closed issue and detail what you've tried and that the closed issue doesn't provide a solution.

Comment: You're not getting a sharing violation (32), so we know the directory isn't opened as the working directory of any process. Renaming a directory will fail with access denied (5) if any files are opened in it or in any subdirectory.

Comment: Good morning all, Have managed to resolve this by inspiration from above.  Found the cause of the fault to be, if a windows explorer window is open and has ANY visibility of the folders being moved (i.e. in the tree on the left or right-pane) then access is denied as it can not move the folders.   If i minimize all the tree's so that the source\destination folders are not visible and select a different sub folder in windows explorer then the os.Rename works as it should, moving all content from A to B really quick (as per linux).

Answer (score 2):

Quoted from comment. solved my issue.

> Found the cause of the fault to be, if a windows explorer window is
>   open and has ANY visibility of the folders being moved (i.e. in the
>   tree on the left or right-pane) then access is denied as it can not
>   move the folders. If i minimize all the tree's so that the
>   source\destination folders are not visible and select a different sub
>   folder in windows explorer then the os.Rename works as it should,
>   moving all content from A to B really quick (as per linux)

Comment: I had to close all files including my IDE to get the command working. Thanks for the help! It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with copying files within the same folder. The following solution works just fine (without closing or minimizing windows):

```
// read original file
origFile, _:= os.ReadFile(filePath)

// create new file with a different name
newFile, _ := os.Create(filePath + ".new")

// print data from original file to new file.
fmt.Fprintf(newFile, "%s", string(origFile))
```